# Compaq presario laptop dual boot - win xp and ubuntu 10.4 - No wireless with ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, wireless-networking

I have a compaq presario laptop dual boot, win xp and ubuntu 10.04, windows boots & uses the wireless no problem. when I boot into ubuntu the wireless icon button is turned off, not enabling me to connect wirelessly. I depress the wireless button but is does not turn on. As long as the wireless button does not glow blue, I know that it is turned off. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is wealth of information at the [Ubuntu forums](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide).

For starters, check that the card is recognised. Open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Why such an old version of Ubuntu? You'll find driver support is much improved in later versions.